# How to make Spock scan for Specification in dependencies

Tags: java, spock

I am making a core framework that will have several client applications.  The clients of the framework must have certain configuration values set for the framework to function properly.  There is a series of Spock Specification files in the framework that will validate if the configuration is appropriate.

In the client, it is possible to subclass each individual Specification file and all is well.  However, the client must know the names of each Specification file and have to stay current if there are new or renamed Specification files.  Is there a way to set Spock to automatically scan for Specification files in a dependency?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. When you say "specification" do you mean the Spock class `Specification` or is the term just coincidence? And what kind of framework are you developing? A test framework? What more do you need than what Spock already offers? And what does "client" mean in this context. I would be really grateful for some actual code and not just abstract theory. There are too many variables here stopping readers from understanding the question.

Comment: @kriegaex:  Thanks for asking clarification.  I made some updates to the question, but it's probably easier to answer some questions directly.  They are Spock Specification classes.  The framework is a generic framework specific to my domain, it is code used directly by the client but also has tests.  The "client" is the code that imports the framework JAR and uses it.

Comment: Does that mean you mix Spock test classes with production code? Or you use Spock as a tool during runtime? I still do not fully understand. Sorry, without any code I am out of here. Good luck to you. And with all due respect: From a user with 13k reputation I would expect that he knows how to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I also don't fully understand the question, but will try to help. When it comes to Spock specifications they're not actually scanned by the spock engine.

Its just like JUnit (I think you're familiar with it :) ) - the test cases are run by some external program. It can be maven surefire plugin or IDE that scans and finds all the relevant classes, but its not a JUnit's work.
The same goes for spock actually, it starts its magic and kind of "accepts" a specification as an input parameter.

You still can create a listener to track a specification execution by creating your own [Spock extension](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/extensions.html) but that's it.